# Copying tables vertically arranged , from multiple files, and paste them horizontally into a master file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

**Source File**
[image: Source File]

**Master/Target**
[image: Master/Target file]

```
    Sub Transfer_Reasons_decl()

    Const srcID As Variant = "G. Reasons declnd & wdrawn clms" ' Name or Index e.g. "Sheet1" or 1
    Const srcAddr1 As String = "B22:E26"
    Const tgtID As Variant = "Reasons declnd & wdrawn clms"  ' Name or Index e.g. "Sheet1" or 1
    Const tgtCol1 As Variant = 3              ' Number or String e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const Pattern As String = "*.xlsx*"
    
    Dim wbPath As String: wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtID)
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, src As Worksheet, tgtCell1 As Range
    Dim Source1 As Variant, Target1 As Variant                       ' Arrays
    Dim Val1 As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, l, m As Long, Name, Count As Long               ' Counters (Longs)
    Dim SrcRng As Range, TgtRng As Range
    
    
    Name = tgt.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim wbname As String: wbname = Dir(wbPath & Pattern)
     Do Until wbname = ""
        If wbname <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        Name = Name + 1
        
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reasons declnd & wdrawn clms").Cells(Name, 1) = wbname
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reasons declnd & wdrawn clms").Cells(Name, 2) = FileDateTime(wbPath & wbname)
        
        
        '******************************************************************
        
            GoSub readSource
            GoSub writeSource
            GoSub writeTarget
            
        End If
        
   WorksheetNotFound:
        wbname = Dir
    Loop
    
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
   MsgBox "Copied data from " & Count & " workbook(s)"
  
   Exit Sub

   readSource:
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & wbname).Worksheets(srcID)
    Set src_B = Workbooks.Open(wbPath & wbname).Worksheets(srcID_B)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then GoTo closeSourceError
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Source1 = src.Range(srcAddr1).Value
    src.Parent.Close False
      
    Return
    
    writeSource:

    ' Write values from Source Array to Target Array.
    'ReDim Target1(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(Source1) * UBound(Source1, 2))
     ReDim Target1(1 To UBound(Source1), 1 To UBound(Source1) * UBound(Source1, 2))
    '**************************************************
     l = 0
   
     For i = 1 To UBound(Source1)
     For j = 1 To UBound(Source1, 2)
              
     l = l + 1
    
     If IsEmpty(Source1(i, j)) Then
     Target1(i, j) = 0
    'Target1(m, l) = 0
     Else
     Target1(i, j) = Source1(i, j)
    'Target1(m, l) = Source1(i, j)
     End If
   
     Next j
     Next i
      
    
     Return
    
    writeTarget:

    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range.
    
     Set tgtCell1 = tgt.Cells(tgt.UsedRange.Rows.Count, tgtCol1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
     tgtCell1.Resize(, UBound(Source1, 2)).Value = Target1
     Count = Count + 1
     Return
    

     closeSourceError:
       src.Parent.Close False 
       On Error GoTo 0
       GoTo WorksheetNotFound
         
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it copies only the first rows and other rows are missing.

Comment: Could you share the link to the original code? I'm quite sure this is one of my 'masterpieces' from some time ago when I was not aware that `Gosub` is deprecated and that using it results in a so-called spaghetti code (unreadable and unmaintainable).

Comment: @VBasic2008 Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141147/copy-paste-using-loop-from-multiple-ranges-to-single-row-into-another-wb

Comment: There is two answer there... which one d u use/accept ? (u may click on the tick/upvote it)

Answer (score 0):

### Group Data

- The code will write the resulting values (no formatting) to the destination worksheet.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**From One Mess into Another**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransferReasonsDecl()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sSearch As String = "DC: TOP 5 REASONS"
    Const sTitlesList As String _
        = "DC: TOP 5 REASONS,#DCs,DC: TOP 5 REASONS,#WCs"
    Const stPattern As String = "Source "
    Const strOffset As Long = -1
    Const sdrOffset As Long = 1
    Const sRows As Long = 5
    Const sCols As Long = 4
       
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    Const drlCount As Long = 2
    Const dclCount As Long = 2
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim aCell As Range: Set aCell = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sws.Columns.Count)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Cells
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = RefFirstOccurrence(srg, aCell, sSearch)
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Populate the Dictionary ('dict'). Each key will contain a jagged array.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim FirstAddress As String: FirstAddress = fCell.Address
    
    Dim sData(0) As Variant
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim uMax As Long
    Dim sTitle As String
    Do
        sTitle = CStr(fCell.Offset(strOffset).Value)
        sData(0) = fCell.Offset(sdrOffset).Resize(sRows, sCols).Value
        If dict.Exists(sTitle) Then
            Arr = dict(sTitle)
            AddItemToArray Arr, _
                fCell.Offset(sdrOffset).Resize(sRows, sCols).Value
            dict(sTitle) = Arr
            If UBound(Arr) > uMax Then
                uMax = UBound(Arr)
            End If
        Else
            dict(sTitle) = sData
        End If
        Set aCell = fCell
        Set fCell = RefFirstOccurrence(srg, aCell, sSearch)
    Loop Until fCell.Address = FirstAddress
    
    ' Populate the Destination Array ('dData').
    
    uMax = uMax + 1
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = uMax * sRows + dclCount
    Dim tCount As Long: tCount = dict.Count
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = tCount * sCols + drlCount
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    Dim n As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Write first row labels.
    dData(1, 1) = "Name"
    dData(2, 1) = "Name"
    For n = 1 To uMax
        For r = 1 To sRows
            dData((n - 1) * sRows + r + dclCount, 1) = stPattern & n
        Next r
    Next n
    
    ' Write second row labels.
    dData(1, 2) = "Name"
    dData(2, 2) = "Name"
    
    n = 0
    Dim Key As Variant
    ' Write first column labels.
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        n = n + 1
        dData(1, (n - 1) * sCols + drlCount + 1) = Key
    Next Key
    
    ' Write second column labels.
    Dim sTitles() As String: sTitles = Split(sTitlesList, ",")
    Dim tUpper As Long: tUpper = UBound(sTitles)
    Dim c As Long
    For n = 1 To tCount
        For c = 0 To tUpper
            dData(2, (n - 1) * sCols + c + drlCount + 1) = sTitles(c)
        Next c
    Next n
    
    ' Write the data.
    n = 0
    Dim t As Long
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        n = n + 1
        Arr = dict(Key)
        For t = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            For r = 1 To sRows
                For c = 1 To sCols
                    dData(t * sRows + dclCount + r, _
                        (n - 1) * sCols + drlCount + c) = Arr(t)(r, c)
                Next c
            Next r
        Next t
    Next Key

    ' Write the values from the Destination Array
    ' to the Destination Range ('drg').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the cell of the first occurrence
'               of a string. The search is performed by rows and starts
'               with the cell after the given cell ('AfterCell')...
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefFirstOccurrence( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal AfterCell As Range, _
    ByVal SearchString As String) _
As Range
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Set RefFirstOccurrence _
        = rg.Find(SearchString, AfterCell, xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
            
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds an item to a zero-based array. Note the 'ByRef' i.e.
'               that the given array ('Arr') is being changed in-place.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub AddItemToArray( _
        ByRef Arr As Variant, _
        ByVal Item As Variant)
    
    If IsEmpty(Arr) Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim NewIndex As Long: NewIndex = UBound(Arr) + 1
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        NewIndex = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To NewIndex)
    Arr(NewIndex) = Item

End Sub
```